# Downloading file from S3 using boto3 inside Docker fails

Tags: python, amazon-s3, docker, boto, boto3

This is failing when I run it inside a Docker container, but works fine when I run it within a virtualenv in OS X. Any idea what could be going wrong? Are there any known issues with Docker+boto?

```
>>> import boto3                                                                                                                   
>>> s3 = boto3.client('s3')                                                                                                        
>>> s3.download_file("mybucket", "myfile.txt", "myfile2.txt")                                                                
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                              
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 104, in download_file                                     
    extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)                                                                                       
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 666, in download_file                                   
    object_size = self._object_size(bucket, key, extra_args)                                                                       
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 729, in _object_size                                    
    Bucket=bucket, Key=key, **extra_args)['ContentLength']                                                                         
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 258, in _api_call                                         
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)                                                                             
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 548, in _make_api_call                                    
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)                                                                             
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Downloading with aws cli works, but inside my python script I'm getting "An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request"

Answer (score 2):

Look at the error: `An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden`

It found the credentials but it didn't have permission to access the bucket. Bottom line: Update your IAM privileges to include `s3:ListBucket` permission for your bucket: `arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*` or just attach the policy `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` to your IAM user/role.

You can try this and see it prints the correct credentials:

```
>>> import botocore.session
>>> session = botocore.session.get_session()

>>> session.get_credentials().access_key
'AKIAABCDEF6RWSGI234Q'

>>> session.get_credentials().secret_key
'abcdefghijkl+123456789+qbcd'
```

Comment: Ok, that helped me rule out issues with the credentials, which is great. Do you think there are specific IAM roles for Docker users?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Docker. If the credentials work on Mac, it should work on Docker too. My guess is the credentials are different. Use the code snippet I posted and check if you are seeing the same credentials on Mac and Docker.

Comment: It's the same exact credentials. :(

Comment: @EvanZamir did you end up finding the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are not setting the correct environment variables. Use `env` to check what is set on your host and set similar variables within the container or pass them through with `-e` to `docker run`.

Edit: Since you specified in your comments that you are using a credentials file, pass that into the container with `-v ~/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials`. This assumes, a proper `HOME` is set and you are using the `root` user. Some images have not done this, and you may need to put it into the root folder at `/.aws/credentials`.
If you have a specific user, the path needs to be in his home folder.

Comment: I'm using a credentials file (~/.aws/credentials) instead of environment variables.

Comment: Then pass it into the container with `-v ~/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials`.

Comment: It is already in the container. Isn't boto supposed to read from it?

Comment: Uh ok :) Yes, boto should read it. You may need to try a few paths. Try putting it into `/.aws` and `/root/.aws`. If your container is using another user, check his home folder.

Comment: Hmm...ok. That's a good point. Maybe it's in the wrong place.

Comment: Welp, I moved the credential file everywhere I could think of, and it didn't help. I then defined env variables, didn't work. Then I used aws configure. No luck. Finally, I tried passing the credentials into the client() function. Still getting the same error. Basically everything suggested here: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#credentials

Answer (score 1):

What fixed the issue for me was to install awscli on my container and update boto3 > 1.4

```
pip install awscli
pip install --upgrade boto3
```

Answer (score 1):

I just chased down a similar issue, and it came down to the fact that the system time was wrong on the machine that returned the 403's when attempting to communicate with S3.  The incorrect system time meant that signatures for requests were being computed incorrectly.  Setting the system time to the correct value solved the problem -- if you ensure that your docker container sets the system time (for example by using NTP), your problem might go away like mine did.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue here with a docker running on windows. The problem was, that the Hyper-V time is stopped, once your pc is going in stand-by mode. This was causing problems, because the timestamp from my request and from the AWS - bucket was different.

What solved the problem for me was to simply restart docker/ my computer...

Also keep in mind, to send your AWS - profile / credentials as environment variables. It seems, that this is a issue from docker:

https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-for-windows-should-resync-vm-time-when-computer-resumes-from-sleep/17825/28

Answer (score 0):

Providing sessionToken does the job for me.
Add ENV AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=**** in Dockerfile along with accesskey and secret_access_key